# sending cv2 image in str format python

Tags: python, opencv, flask, numpy-ndarray

i know that this is a noob question but i can't find anything about it.

I'm writing a .py program for transmitting(server side) the input from a videocamera to another pc(client side), i'm using opencv and i can easily read the data from the camera and manipulate them.
Now, on my server side when i get a GET requests i respond with this code

```
def test():
    img = start(0,0)#return a cv2 image elaborated and standard cv2 image color scale
    return str(img)#send to the client the img in string format
```

the client receive the correct data, i've saved the str(img) of serverSide and the received str from the client and they're the same.

this is the client side code:

```
txt = resp.text#get the text who's received back
txt = np.array(txt)#convert to a numpy array
#print(txt) #debug
cv2.imshow('image',txt)#show image
```

the problem is on the last line of client and give me this error

**TypeError: Expected Ptr< cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'**

but the txt string is a numpy array, and the data in it are exactly the same as the client side(btw if i show the img on server side it's ok), any suggestions?

**PLEASE REALLY NEED HELP**

(full code: https://github.com/ThomasAndreatta/opencvServer/tree/master)

Comment: You probably need to convert to a different datatype. Try using converto() function

Comment: Please follow the instructions in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/kylehounslow/767fb72fde2ebdd010a0bf4242371594)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numpy array needs to be type `uint8`. Add an extra line of code before `cv2.imshow(...)`

```
txt = txt.astype(np.uint8)
```

You can check what type the variable is before you show it using `whos`. Also, to prevent confusion, changing the variable name to reflect the change in type would be sensible.